# VS Code keymap for switching to the tab on the right?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keymapping

The left equivalent for what I'm looking for is `back`. I can't find `forward`.

`go forward`,  on the other hand, is completely different.

(I'm on a mac).

Answer (score 1):

Open Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts and see if there is a keymap for wanted action. If not, create it.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

If I got your question right, commands you need are "Focus next pane", which on Windows are "Alt + Left/Right arrow"